# wxwidget opencv conflict with 3rd lib like jpeg, png, zlib, tiff

Tags: opencv, wxwidgets, conflict

I work on winXP, and using gcc4.7.

I built OpenCV 2.4.2 static lib, they have `liblibjpeg.a` `liblibpng.a` `liblibtiff.a` `libzlib.a` and other `.a` file.

Then I built wxwidgets294 on shared and get `libwxjpeg.a` `libwxpng.a` `libwxtiff.a` `libwxzlib.a` and other `.a`/`.dll` file.

So when I using OpenCV on wxwidgets, they conflict. When I link `-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng -lwxzlib -lwxmsw29ud` the wxwidget can work, but OpenCV can't, like `imread` will fail (it get empty mat). When I link `-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -llibjasper -llibtiff -llibjpeg -llibpng -lwxmsw29ud -lzlib` the wxwidgets can't work, it exit as soon as it run.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I got new situations. use link option 
"-mthreads
-Wl,-Bstatic -lopencv_highgui
-Wl,-Bstatic -lopencv_imgproc
-Wl,-Bstatic -lopencv_core
-Wl,-Bstatic -llibjasper
-Wl,-Bstatic -lwxjpeg
-Wl,-Bstatic -llibtiff
-Wl,-Bstatic -lzlib
-Wl,-Bdynamic -lwxmsw29u"
the app run well, but cv::imread jpg image will crash only in wxwidgets event fun.

Comment: use link option 
"-mthreads
-Wl,-Bstatic -lopencv_highgui
-Wl,-Bstatic -lopencv_imgproc
-Wl,-Bstatic -lopencv_core
-Wl,-Bdynamic -lwxmsw29u
-Wl,-Bstatic -llibjasper
-Wl,-Bstatic -llibjpeg
-Wl,-Bstatic -lzlib"
the app run well, but cv::imread jpg image will return empty mat on any place.

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain why it can't work (do you mean "crashes" by "exit"? If so, have you tried debugging it?) but in general the best is to link all the libraries you use more than once as shared libraries and not have multiple (and perhaps different) copies of static ones.

At least wxWidgets can be configured to use the shared libraries already present on your system if they're installed. You probably don't have them though, which is why it falls back on compiling the versions included in wx itself.

Comment: it can't work mean that it either exit or get empty mat. In exit status, debug it also exit as soon as debug run. In get empty mat status, it's ok,only imread get empty mat. maybe it should rebuild opencv and wxwidgets with the same 3rd lib.

Comment: Sorry, I simply don't understand the above. You'll need to be more clear and possibly more detailed if you need any more help.